# The -itsoffset parameter of FFmpeg is having no effect

Tags: ffmpeg

When rendering my animation video with ffmpeg, I want my video to start with 28-odd seconds of silencebefore the soundtrack begins.

(Well, I really want it to be 0.28 seconds but making it longer makes debugging easier.)

That's easy enough. According to [the manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au) and [others](http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/fixing-audio-sync-with-ffmpeg/), it is all about adding the `-itsoffset` parameter before the audio input you wish to delay.

Here's my command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -itsoffset 28.84 -i soundtrack.wav -framerate 30 -i %d.png -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 generated.mp4
```

It generates the video, but the soundtrack starts immediately.

I am stll new to FFmpeg, so I assume I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `adelay` filter for MP4.

```
ffmpeg -y -i soundtrack.wav -framerate 30 -i %d.png -af "adelay=28840|28840" -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 generated.mp4
```

Comment: Will try that out.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I still don't understand the reason why my way didn't work, and I have to assume it is a bug, but that could still be wrong.

Comment: It is likely a bug. Try with `-copyts` immediately after the itsoffset.

Comment: Apparently itsoffset only works for video inputs, not audio

Comment: Not so.  Unless the demuxer sends packets with no timestamps, itsoffset should work with all inputs

Answer (score 1):

There is an open ticket against [FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1349) from 4 years ago, that suggests that this is a bug with the mp4 container

> 2) outfile has expected playback behavior with .ts and .mkv containers.
>   3) It does not work with .avi (no timestamps, so not a surprise)
>   4) It does not work with .mp4 container (a bug?)

Sure enough, when I use an mkv file, it works.
(Well, in VLC, but no sound at all in the Windows 10 "Films & TV" viewer.)